# Fastest way to set values in a numpy where conditions is met

Tags: python, numpy

Say maxVal = 160 and minVal = 100, Now I want to set all pixel of the image whose values that are NOT in the range of minVal to maxVal equal to 0 or black.  I can do this by looping to the image pixel value.  But is there way to do this in a numPyish way?  Image is defined below.

```
img = cv2.imread("location", 0)
```

Comment: `img[(img < min_val) | (img > max_val)] = 0`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Please write it as answer to close the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can index Numpy arrays with your conditions directly:

```
img[(img < min_val) | (img > max_val)] = 0
```